# How to remove JSON schema from the response from AWS API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vuejs2, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS API gateway as a proxy to DynamoDb as per this documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

When tested in the API gateway, the result is as below:

```
{
  "Count": 6,
  "Items": [
    {
      "mini_description": {
        "S": "A veg sandwich"
      },
      "item_description": {
        "S": "A veg sandwich filled with a lot of healthy vegetables"
      },
      "id": {
        "S": "6d0e0870-......-c5ccfbc0424c"
      },
      "image_url": {
        "S": "https://......png"
      },
      "price": {
        "N": "25"
      },
      "name": {
        "S": "Veg Sandwich"
      },
      "item_type": {
        "S": "Main Dish"
      }
    },
    {
      "mini_description": {
        "S": "A normal hot coffee"
      },.....
```

I need it in the following format:

```
{
  "Count": 6,
  "Items": [
    {
      "mini_description": "A veg sandwich",
      "item_description": "A veg sandwich filled with a lot of healthy vegetables",
      "id": "6d0e0870-.......-c5ccfbc0424c",
      "image_url": "https://.......png",
      "price": 25,
      "name": "Veg Sandwich",
      "item_type": "Main Dish"
    },
    {
      "mini_description": "A normal hot coffee",............
```

Is there any procedure to change this through Integration response of API gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this by using the following mapping template in integration response of the GET method in API gateway:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "Items": [
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items)
    {
      "mini_description" : "$elem.mini_description.S",
      "item_description" : "$elem.item_description.S",
      "id" : "$elem.id.S",
      "image_url" : "$elem.image_url.S",
      "price" : $elem.price.N,
      "name" : "$elem.name.S",
      "item_type" : "$elem.item_type.S"
    }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end

#end
  ]
}
```

Comment: I get a validation error when pasting this answer in the console:                                         
 Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid content type specified: #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) { "Items": [ #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) { "mini_description" : "$elem.mini_description.S", "item_description" : "$elem.item_description.S", "id" : "$elem.id.S", "image_url" : "$elem.image_url.S", "price" : $elem.price.N, "name" : "$elem.name.S", "item_type" : "$elem.item_type.S" }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end #end ] }]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to unmarshall the data if you have API gateway going directly to DynamoDB. However, you can add a Lambda function in between API gateway and DynamoDB, and then use [the unmarshall function from Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property) (or any other preferred language) to remove the DynamoDB JSON elements.